# Why does getting members behave inconsistently?

Tags: c#-4.0, roslyn

When trying to obtain a collection of types in a given compilation, I've gotten myself all confused as to which way to approach the issue. Essentially, methods that would seem to return results do not, and vice-versa. Below is output from a debug session Immediate Window, where `appCompilation` is of type `Compilation` (natch).

```
**appCompilation.GlobalNamespace.GetMembers()**
Count = 14
    [0]: "Namespace Registration"
    [1]: "Namespace Payments"
    [2]: "Namespace Foo"
    [3]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [4]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [5]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [6]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [7]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [8]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [9]: "NamedType <Module>"
    [10]: "Namespace Conference"
    [11]: "Namespace System"
    [12]: "NamedType <>f__AnonymousType0<<OrderId>j__TPar>"
    [13]: "Namespace Infrastructure"
**appCompilation.GlobalNamespace.GetTypeMembers()**
{System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator<Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.NamedTypeSymbol>}
    source: null
**appCompilation.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers()**
{System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator<Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.NamespaceSymbol>}
    source: null
```

So my question is this: 
When I call `.GetTypeMembers()` on a Symbol of `Kind` == `Namespace`, I get null. 
When I call `.GetNamespaceMembers()` for the same symbol, I also get null. 
Yet, when I call `.GetMembers()` I get namespaces and types galore!

Weirder still, I can place this statement into a watch window and get non-empty, non-null results!

`appCompilation.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers(), results`

Possibly relevant:
Initiating execution of a query doesn't seem to happen when I expect, but I'm not exactly sure how that how or even why I should have to worry about that... calling `.ToList()` sometimes will trigger execution. I had thought that even though many methods provide a `CancellationToken` parameter, they all run synchronously. A problem too is that the various `GetXXX()` methods return either `ReadOnlyArray` or `IEnumerable`; the read-only doesn't seem to pick up the same behavior from the LINQ extension methods the same way that IEnumerable does.

Judging from a surface scan of debugging output, it looks like `GetTypeMembers` and its' ilk wrap `GetMembers()` with an `.OfType<>` call. Maybe it's in that translation things are getting borked?

At any rate, the inconsistency of accessing and executing queries has been quite painful, so I'm hoping that someone can help me understand what I'm missing that is making things seem so non-deterministic.

EDIT: After iterating against it a bit, I found that you just have to do a recursive search through the symbol tree, and that query syntax can be a much easier approach than lambda expressions sometimes... and oh yes - PEBKAC, since it seems that the Immediate Window was hindering more than helping debug efforts.

Final Passing query sample that retrieves all types from a given Compilation, up to a level of three namespace nestings or so (need more tests to cover those cases):

From this (and this is far better than some other attempts!)

```
appCompilation.Assembly.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetNamespaceMembers().Select(y => y.GetNamespaceMembers()))
    .SelectMany(x => x, (symbols, symbol) => symbol.GetTypeMembers())
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

To this (still not fully recursive, but good enough for now):

```
from glob in appCompilation.Assembly.GlobalNamespace
    .GetMembers()
    .OfType<NamespaceOrTypeSymbol>()
from childNs in glob
    .GetMembers()
    .OfType<NamespaceSymbol>()
from childTypes in childNs
    .GetTypeMembers()
select childTypes;
```

Comment: Isn't this just problem with the Immediate window? What happens if you actually try to enumerate the result using a `foreach`?

Comment: I only ran that statement in the immediate window after test failure caused me to put a breakpoint and debug to the failure site :)

Comment: FWIW, fixing a failing test using nCrunch is actually not far off an iterative experience than using the Immediate window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only a limitation with the Immediate window, unrelated to Roslyn.

For example with the following code:

```
var ints = new object[] { 2 }.OfType<int>();
```

I get this output in the Immediate window:

```
ints
{System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator<int>}
    source: null
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TResult>.Current: 0
    System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current: 0
```

But if I iterate the collection using a `foreach`, or use Results View in a watch window, it works correctly.

The reason you see what you do is because `Enumerable.OfType()` is written using an iterator block, which generates the iterator type. The iterator type has some fields with unspeakable names, including `<>3__source` which holds the original source (the array in my example). It also has one field with a normal name: `source`, which is set in the call to `GetEnumerator()`. Since you didn't call that method yet, `source` is `null`.

Comment: It's possible that I'm hiding my original problem with new ones in the Immediate window. I'll revise my post the failing test code

Comment: PEBKAC! You were correct - the Immediate window was getting in the way of figuring it out. Once I simplified my tests down enough to gain faith in them, I was able to iterate to a solution